# Django South migrations directory outside django project

Tags: django, django-south

I'm trying to setup South in a way that the location of the migrations directories will be outside the Django directory. I can use SOUT_MIGRATION_MODULES to change the location of the directories within Django (to every place with an init file), but that's not enough for me. Unfortunately, SOUT_MIGRATION_MODULES doesn't accept full paths as input.

Can anybody explain how I can make South to place the migrations directories to a specified path outside the Django directory?

**Update:**
This is the current directory structure:

- Data
- Django project

  - Project name

    - settings.py
  - Django app

    - migrations

Idealy I would like south to puth the migrations folder in the Data directory, which is outside the entire django project.

Answer (score 2):

As it takes *any* module, just create a module outside your project and add it to your python path, e.g.:

```
SOUTH_MIGRATION_MODULES = {
    'blog': '<my_foreign_module>.migrations.blog',
}
```

Another way would be to monkey patch South's `Migrations` class, but really, you should avoid this hackery.

```
from south.migration.base import Migrations

def migrations_dir(self):
    return #my_ugly_hack

Migrations.migrations_dir = migrations_dir
```

Comment: I have been playing with this, but I don't get it to work. I have put the directory structure in the original post as clarification.

Comment: Did you create an init file inside the data directory and have you added it to your python path accordingly?

Comment: I did, I guess it has something to do with the server I'm using.